# Getting error 'Some bytes have been replaced with the Unicode substitution character while loading file ... with Unicode (UTF-8)"

Tags: unicode, utf-8, substitution

I am getting an error when trying to open my VS2015 project:

> Some bytes have been replaced with the Unicode substitution character while loading file ... with Unicode (UTF-8)

This seems to be related to one VB file in the project which now displays as a section of normal code followed by gobbledegook further down the file.

Here is the part of the file at which this happens:

```
timeString = CType(worksheet.Cells(EndTimeCell(0), EndTimeCell(1) + col).Value, String)
endtimeValue = DateTime.FromOADate(timeString).TimeOfDay

'Combine Date And time into a single DateTime
combinedStartDateTime = startdateValue.Add(starttim4F�r2��+�G��� ,j���
|2�$�{,���ܴ���0j.2-���8h�\���WI޳J�/���Rs�S�0��Dg,[6+O�����=Z��?����.ZmF%��`B�s��n�21Q���)0s3�*���W�q��^�h��6    H$��+�!�֏��Z�7�b    �xȯ�E3z>�a��    Ê���7�ŉ=�|Ă턨׫���udx��6JT��j�����z�.��X�{>��_�1�?&.ͥ7*���M7N�mrN�XVw�+�e>Ms�=7e)�
ݚ�m�?�(o
```

This continues to the end of the file.

Is there any way of resolving this and getting the VB back? It worked ok last week, so no idea what has caused this, unless it is some kind of Windows update that has done it.

I tried 'converting' the offending file to UTF-8 format in Notepad, but this made no difference.

Comment: The file either has invalid utf-8 sequences or is outright using a different encoding.

Comment: Windows likes UTF-8 w/ BOM encoding. Without the BOM it’s probably assuming Windows-1252.

Comment: @MarkTolonen the error message implies it's trying to use UTF-8 so the BOM is probably there.  But since it contains invalid bytes it seems likely that the encoding really is Windows-1252 and the BOM doesn't belong.

Comment: @MarkRansom I hadn't looked that closely at the data.  Looks to me more like file corruption, actually.  Bad sector on disk?  Windows-1252 loaded as UTF-8 would still display ASCII characters correctly.  This just goes off the rails.

Comment: @MarkTolonen thanks for the replies. I worry it might be a corrupted file, is there any way of checking this for sure? I can try to open it using 'Open With' in VS, which 'Encoding' option would be worth trying with this? (unless you think this is a waste of time). Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: It just looks corrupted to me. Most encodings understand the ASCII character set just fine, and it looks like total garbage starting in the middle of what looks like an ASCII variable name. I can’t think of an encoding that would do that

Comment: @MarkTolonen Ok thanks. I do use a repository but hadn't checked this piece of code in for a while so it looks like I'll have to re-write what I've lost unless there is some other way of getting back to a previous version